# Derive the gradient matrices w.r.t. W1 and W2 and backprop equation in a Residual Network

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent, residual-networks

How would I go about deriving gradient matrices w.r.t. W1 and W2 and backpropagation equation in a residual block that is a part of a larger ResNet network with forward propagation expressed as:

$$ F(x) =  \mathrm{W}_{2}^{} \mathrm{g}_{1}^{}(\mathrm{W}_{1}^{}x) $$

$$ y =  \mathrm{g}_{2}^{} (F(x) + x) $$

and

$$
\mathrm{g}_{1}^{}, \mathrm{g}_{2}^{}
$$

are component-wise non-linear activation functions.

EDIT:

For the gradient matrix derivation I followed the same logic as in the link below, but I got stuck at this step:

[image]

and in the next step with taking derivatives, why they must equal to 0. I wanted to square my approach with ideas from others.

Source link:

https://towardsdatascience.com/deriving-the-backpropagation-equations-from-scratch-part-2-693d4162e779#b8ae

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?